# How to parse TZ format time with non-GMT time zone

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

I have time string in two formats.

```
2019-03-01T22:22:50.591-08:00   
2019-03-01T22:22:50.591Z
```

I am using following Java snippet to parse

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS" +
              ".SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
Date date = df.parse(dateString);
```

Its working on second string but failing on first. What common code can be there to parse both of them?

Comment: [`ZonedDateTime.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-). But I'll let Basil go into the detail.

Comment: This function needs a DateTimeFormatter for string pattern. I am not able to find correct pattern.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Stay away from `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You don’t need an explicit formatter: `OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString)` works for both example strings.

Comment: Both `-08:00` and  `Z` are UTC offsets. `Z` means UTC (offset zero or “Zulu”). So both strings are really in the same format. It’s the international standard ISO 8601 format.

Comment: @shmosel No, not `ZonedDateTime`, You can get by with that, but it is misleading as there is only an offset-from-UTC (hours-minutes-seconds) in the inputs, not a time zone (`Continent/Region`). Better would be `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-03-01T22:22:50.591-08:00" )`.

Comment: @BasilBourque I was waiting for that. It does work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"`

```
Date parsed1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.US).parse("2019-03-01T22:22:50.591Z");
System.out.println(parsed1); // Fri Mar 01 16:22:50 CST 2019

Date parsed2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.US).parse("2019-03-01T22:22:50.591-08:00");
System.out.println(parsed2); // Sat Mar 02 00:22:50 CST 2019
```

As Basil points out below, these also work if you are running Java 8+ or a backport of JSR 310:

```
    OffsetDateTime parsed1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-03-01T22:22:50.591Z");
    System.out.println(parsed1); // Fri Mar 01 16:22:50 CST 2019

    OffsetDateTime parsed2 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-03-01T22:22:50.591-08:00");
    System.out.println(parsed2); // Sat Mar 02 00:22:50 CST 2019
```

Comment: Yup, agree, but did not want to turn too many screws at the same time. I have two clients that still run JBoss EAP 4.2 in production and won't use a JSR 310 backport... Have edited.